# primefaces ocultar columna en excel p:dataExporter

Tags: java, primefaces

Tengo una tabla como la siguiente:

```
<p:dataTable var="car" value="#{dtBasicView.cars}">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <p:outputLabel style="float:left">Resultados de búsqueda</p:outputLabel>
            <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="car" fileName="coches"/>
        </p:outputPanel>                                                          
    </f:facet>
    <p:column headerText="Id">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.id}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Year">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.year}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Brand">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.brand}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Color">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.color}" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Ahora al exportar el excel me imprime las las 4 columnas: `id - year - brand - color`.

¿Cómo se puede ocultar una columna solo en el excel, pero que se siga viendo en la web?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usa `exportable="false"` en las columnas deseadas. Pongo tu ejemplo ocultado la columna year

```
<p:dataTable var="car" value="#{dtBasicView.cars}">
<f:facet name="header">
    <p:outputLabel style="float:left">Resultados de búsqueda</p:outputLabel>
        <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="car" fileName="coches"/>
    </p:outputPanel>                                                          
</f:facet>
<p:column headerText="Id">
    <h:outputText value="#{car.id}" />
</p:column>

<p:column headerText="Year" exportable="false">
    <h:outputText value="#{car.year}" />
</p:column>

<p:column headerText="Brand">
    <h:outputText value="#{car.brand}" />
</p:column>

<p:column headerText="Color">
    <h:outputText value="#{car.color}" />
</p:column>
```

[Documentacion Oficial](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/dataexporter/excludeColumns.xhtml)